# Django admin show success message when saving model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, message

I'm new to django and trying to get a success message to show when I save a form in the admin. I want it to show at the top of the page which lists all items for the model (changelist page I think).

I've had a look through several posts here and the django documentation and worked out I need to use the messages framework and overwrite the save_model method in my model admin, here's what I have so far:

```
class scoutGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
        super(scoutGroupAdmin,self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

I've tried multiple versions of the above but no matter what I do when I go back to the changelist page there is no message displayed. Again I'm just learning django so please let me know if I'm missing something obvious !

Thanks

Comment: Have you remembered to [register](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin) your model admin?

Comment: Hi,

sorry I didn't get a notification of the comment. Yes I've got it registered with this line:
admin.site.register(scoutGroups,scoutGroupAdmin) .

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
class scoutGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
        obj.save()
```

Do not call "super". The "obj" is the instance to be saved. The "change" is a boolean that tells you if the instance is being created or changed.

See the docs: [django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)

Answer (score 0):

Add **"obj.save()"** and remove **"super()"** as shown below:

```py
class scoutGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save() # Here
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
        # super(scoutGroupAdmin,self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```